# Table-like Dynamicly Created Data Structure

Tags: c#, csv, data-structures

I want to read in the contents of a CSV file into some kind of table-like data structure.  I need a data structure capable of adapting to any number of columns of fundamental data types (ie. string, int, float).  I already have code that reads in values as strings from a file and I'm pretty sure I can design some logic to easily identify each datatype for conversion to strong types (for my purposes anyway).  For instance:

```
Name, Age, Sex

"John",34,M

"Jill",27,F  etc..
```

becomes:

```
string, uint, enum
```

Should I try to create a struct or class with these unique fields (perhaps using Reflection) and then try to store these in a List?  How would this be done?

I'm expecting that there will be many thousands of rows of data.  I will be accessing the data one row at a time normally in a sequential fashion in memory.

I know that [File Helpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/) can do this sort of thing but I'm wondering how I might do it in my own code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use a DataTable? It's a strongly typed tabular datastructure. You don't need to use it in the context of a database.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it will do the job!

Answer (score 2):

You can use either `DataTable` or Tuple as follows

```
var table = new Tuple<string, int, string>("Rajesh",25,"Male");
```

I would suggest `DataTable` where you can have some built-in methods